# Is there a Java equivalent of Python's rpm library?

Tags: java

There is a problem we want to code in Java.
Given an rpm package filename, we need to get the name, version, release and architecture from the following rpm filename format:

```
<name>-<version>-<release>.<architecture>.rpm
```

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/ladbi/rpm-packages-naming-convention.html#GUID-04FBD99C-77A8-4E31-9C8D-5B6B2EAE68DB

Is there a Java equivalent of Python's rpm library that could automatically give us name, version, release and architecture attribute values?

Any feedback or hint on how to approach this with Java will be much appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: A whole library to disassemble a formatted String, seems like over kill to me.  Have you searched google for a java rpm library? perhaps source forge or github? or maybe even maven central?

Comment: Library recommendations are explicitly off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see why you need a library. Can you not use a simple regex?

```
    String rpm = "oracle-database-ee-18c-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.+)-(.+)-(.+)\\.(.+)\\.rpm");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(rpm);
    if (!matcher.matches()) 
        throw new IllegalStateException("not matching correct format");
    String name = matcher.group(1);
    String version = matcher.group(2);
    String release = matcher.group(3);
    String arch = matcher.group(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use a simple regex for this, though I am not entirely familiar with the format:

```java
import java.util.regex.*;

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)\\.([^.]+)\\.rpm");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("name-version-release.architecture.rpm");
if (matcher.matches()) {
    System.out.println("Name: " + matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println("Version: " + matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println("Release: " + matcher.group(3));
    System.out.println("Architecture: " + matcher.group(4));
}
```

Would print something like this:

```
Name: name
Version: version
Release: release
Architecture: architecture
```